# How to prevent a long running request in ASP.NET 4.5 from timing out

Tags: asp.net, webforms, windows-server-2012

**Never mind that its not a best practice but for a custom requirement (there will only be a couple of users for the app & no concurrent access)**, I need to set a very large execution timeout value so that request can take even hours to complete. In the Web.config file, I've  set the value for the [executionTimeout attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (that defines the number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET) of the httpRuntime element as 3000 (8+ hours)

I have set the debug attribute in the compilation element to False as it is a pre-condition for setting a large timeout value.

The web application runs on ASP.NET 4.5 and IIS 8.5/Windows Server 2012.

Even after I set such a high value for executionTimeout property, a page request times out after 1 hour. How can I make the page not to time out?

Is there a maximum value for executionTimeout beyond which it cannot be increased? Is some system setting value in IIS or Windows Server 2012 forcing the executionTimeout value in web.config from taking effect?

Comment: WOW, odd question! Could be your application pool getting recycled. Does this request report progress? why do you need to maintain the channel for so long? could you not just run the request on a task or thread and just save the out come for the user when they return? sorry if i am not getting the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it's not working for you. But we've tried setting the following values which works for us.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="4800" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
```

along with

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">
```